# Add time to datetime and return the date and time javascript

Tags: javascript

In my application am selecting "startdate" and "starttime" from comboboxes.

then i need to add 1 day 1 hour 20 min to that selected datetime.

how to do that any suggestion

Comment: `dateObj.setHours();` and `dateObj.setMinutes();` will help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Update your question with code and HTML